# How do I preserve picking pepper to last a year

Tags: chili-peppers, pepper, bell-peppers

What is ratio of vinegar and salt for picking pepper to last a year

Comment: what recipes have you looked at ?  IMO, the most important aspect of pickling is how you will sterilize the containers.

Comment: Dayor welcome and thank you for your question. In order for the community here to best help you it would be good to know what you have either already tried or what references you may be employing to prompt your question. What is the source of your concern(s)?